# mysql Left Join, group by with count

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - one for courses and one for people attending the course.

Both are joined by course_id

> table 1:  firstaid - has all the course names
>
> table 2: first_aid_att - records attendees and captures first aid
>   course id

I would like to get a count of attendees per course.

I have got a join working but don't know how to do the group by and count.

```
SELECT * 
FROM firstaid
LEFT JOIN first_aid_att ON firstaid.course_id = first_aid_att.course_id
ORDER BY `sortDate` ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT f1.*, COUNT(f2.course_id)
FROM firstaid f1
LEFT JOIN first_aid_att f2 ON (f1.course_id = f2.course_id)
GROUP BY f1.course_id
ORDER BY f2.sortDate
```